# Why Mahadev repeatedly asked Ma Parvati to abandon her body?

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shakti

During initiation process of Ma Parvati as Mother of very Existence, Mahadev repeatedly asked Ma Parvati to give-up her current body and assume new one and learn required skills whenever she committed some gruesome mistake as Mahadev considered those mistake of very grave nature.

For example, Mahadev made it clear to Ma Parvati that it is not the proper time&day (*Tithi*) and she is not ready to endure pain of initiation into *tantra* as she is weak after long years of excruciating *Tapasya*. But mother was adamant and asked him to go ahead. In turn Mahadev asked her not to dose-off during process. Unfortunately, she does and Mahadev instantly ask her to leave body and take rebirth among fishermen and learn power of concentration.

It is said that Mahadev asked her to take so many births before actually initiating her as Jagad Amba (Mother of Existence).

Here is my question,

> Why Mahadev asked Jagad Amba to give-up her body every time she committed mistake during initiation process?

Instead,

1. He could have stated the outcome of her being adamant and taking wrong decision or going against his judgement.
2. Or, he could have taught her all the skills required to get initiated.
3. Or, he could have stated clearly all the prerequisites need to get initiated.

I am asking this question because very plank-length<sub>1</sub> action of Mahadev would not be without a reason. So, asking his beloved to be departed for long periods of time would be very harsh for him as well.

`Request: Please ask question(s), if you have any doubt or confusion regarding my description before drafting your answer. In the past, people tried to help me but their answers did not cited the explanation I was looking for or interested in. They changed the context or meaning without consulting OP. I'll delete this paragraph once I accept the appropriate answer.`

<sub>1. Plank length is a smallest measurement in know universe</sub>

Comment: From where do you get this information "Why Mahadev repeatedly asked Ma Parvati to abandon her body?" I think it's shown in one episode of DKDM. But I'm not sure from which scripture they are taking this story... It might just be a folklore!...

Comment: @Tejaswee It is collective knowledge from DKDM and The Srimad Devi Bhagawatam and personal discourse with religiously inclined people. But, I can't pin-point exact sloka or chapter of any kind. Also, if you read about Mahavtar Baba (who could be Mahadev or Paramahamsa) you come across a story were he asked his one disciple to give away his body as he was insisting of instant initiation without burning his karma.

Comment: At least share what you found in " Srimad Devi Bhagawatam" otherwise it looks like a question with baseless claim. @ubi BTW DKDM may not be a valid source.